# Chromecast Discovery Issue on Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I am using [CastCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android)  in my android video cast app. My app works well on several devices I've tested like Nexus 4/5/7 and so on. But when I was testing it on Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1, I encountered a Chromecast discovery issue.

1. my app could not display the Chromecast icon on the action bar at first
2. after waiting for a long time, about 10 minutes, the Chromecast icon appears, and from that moment on, my app work well.
3. after reboot the Chromecast, this issue comes again
4. at the same environment on Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1, Youtube, Google Play Movies & TV  works without any problem. However, I checked out and built the CastHelloText, MediaRouter-Cast-Button and [CastVideos](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android) project from GitHub, they all have the same issue as my app on on Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1.

I've already updated the Google Play service to ver 4.3, but that didn't help.

Any advice is very appreciated.

Comment: We are looking into some discovery/connectivity issues in general but they are usually not device specific. Do you have other versions of Galaxy Note so we can find a pattern?

Comment: Note that the YT and Google Play Movies and TV do their discovery based on the old approach (UPnP based) but apps based on the official SDK do mDNS based discovery and that is why you see two different behaviors.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the two different behaviors on one device. We have no other version of Galaxy Note. Is there any workaround to make the discovery works normally on my device base on the offcial SDK?

Comment: Since I don't know why that device is behaving differently, I can't make any recommendation. Do you happen to have access to another identical device to see if this is happening across Galaxy Notes 10.1 or it is isolated to that one particular device?

Comment: This is also happening on our app on the Note 10.1. It looks like discovery is broken on that one device.

Comment: Logged under the google cast SDK issue list. https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=258. So far there is no movement